# What is the rank of $\sum_{i=1}^k \vec{u}_i \vec{v}_i^T$ with $\{ \vec{u}_i \}$ and $\{ \vec{v}_i \}$ each linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> Let $A = \sum_{i=1}^k \vec{u}_i \vec{v}_i^T$, where $\vec{u}_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\vec{v}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that $\{ \vec{u}_i \}_{i=1}^k$ are linearly independent and $\{ \vec{v}_i \}_{i=1}^k$ are linearly independent. Assume $m > n > k$.
>
> What is the rank of $A$?

Let $A_i = \vec{u}_i \vec{v}_i^T$ so that $A = \sum_{i=1}^k A_i$.

Column $j$ of $A_i$ is $(\vec{v}_i)_j \vec{u}_i$. The rank of each $A_i$ is one since all columns are multiples of a single vector $\vec{u}_i$.

Column $j$ of $A$ is $\sum_{i=1}^k (\vec{v}_i)_j \vec{u}_i$. It seems the columns of $A$ may or may not be linearly independent. Is that correct? Then the rank can be from $1$ to $k$. The wording of the question suggests that the rank of $A$ is $k$ but I don't see why this is necessarily the case.

Comment: I think the answer is $k$. If $\{\vec u_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are all linearly independent and $\{\vec u_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are independent, wouldn't $A_i$ necessarily be independent? For some $r$ and $s$, $A_r + A_s$ would have to be rank 2 because the independence of $\vec v_r$ and $\vec v_s$ would guarantee that the columns of $A_r$ and $A_s$ don't have the same relationship. That is, if columns 2 and 3 of a 3x3 $A_r$ are $p\vec u_r$ and $q\vec u_r$ then the same can't be said for columns 2 and 3 of $A_s$ and $\vec u_s$. A rigorous argument escapes me, but I think this is the key idea.

Comment: If it isn't clear from context, $p$ and $q$ are constants.

Comment: I think looking at the columns is a hard way to show this. Maybe try to see if you can find an $x$ the domain such that $\sum_{i=1}^k u_i(v_i^Tx) = w$ for any $w = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i u_i$.

Comment: write $A=UV^T$ where $U$ and $V$ each have a left inverse (why?) and conclude $k\leq \text{rank}\big(UV^T\big)\leq k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the one hand, for any $v \in \mathbf{R}^m$, we have that
$$
Av
= \sum_{i=1}^k (v_i^\mathrm{T}v) u_i
\in \mathrm{span}\{u_1, \dotsc, u_k\},
$$
so that $\mathrm{Im}(A) \subseteq \mathrm{span}\{u_1, \dotsc, u_k\}$

On the other hand, let $u = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i u_i$ for $a_i \in \mathbf{R}$.
Let $V$ be the $k\times n$ matrix whose $i$th row is $v_i^{\mathrm{T}}$,
Since the $v_i$ are linearly independent, this matrix has rank $k$ and so is surjective.
In particular, there is a $w\in \mathbf{R}^m$ that solves $Vw = a$, where $a$ is the vector whose $i$th entry is $a_i$.
Equating entries, this means that $(Vw)_i = v_i^{\mathrm{T}} w = a_i$

But then, we have that
$$
Aw
= \sum_{i=1}^k (v_i^\mathrm{T}w) u_i
= \sum_{i=1}^k a_i u
= u,
$$
so that $\mathrm{span}\{u_1, \dotsc, u_k\} \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(A)$.

Hence, the rank of $A$ is
$$
\mathrm{\dim}\, \mathrm{Im}(A)
= \mathrm{\dim}\, \mathrm{span}\{u_1, \dotsc, u_k\},
$$
which is $k$ since th $u_i$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

The outer product $(u,v)\mapsto uv^T$ makes $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ a tensor product of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. Tensor rank in this context is just matrix rank. But the tensor rank of a sum of tensor products of linearly independent vectors is just the number of summands, which in this case is $k$.